# Issue with and if statement containing a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to the wonderful world of a spy" << endl;
    cout << "Today we are to decode some information that has been provided." <<endl;
    string response;
    cout << "Are you ready?" << endl;
    cin >> response;
    if (response == "yes", "y", "Yes", "Y"){
        cout << "Alright, let's go!!!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Well, too bad. We are going to do it anyways." << endl;
    }
}
```

[Exact Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhpKb.png) Here is my code thus far. I can't get it to not say "Alright, let's go!!! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let's start with an actual code snippet, not a screenshot. Please paste the code into your question.

Comment: Please don't try to guess the syntax. The result of that `if` statement is the evaluation of `"Y"`, which is always `true` (the rest is discarded, they have no side effects). Please get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your if statement conditions are wrong.

```
    if(response == "yes" || response == "y" || response == "Yes" || response == "Y")
    {
        //then do whatever...
    }else{
        //do it anyway...
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The line `if (response == "yes", "y", "Yes", "Y")` doesn't do what you think it does.  The comma operator evaluates each of its operands, discards the result on the left and takes the result on the right as the result of the expression.  So what you wrote is equivalent to `if ("Y")`.  You need to use the logical OR operator to combine your different cases.  Like this `if (response == "yes" || response == "y" || response == "Yes" || response == "Y")`.